# Can't install grpcio on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.5?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Python 3.7.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.
Trying to install ray and tensorflow packages but getting errors installing one of the
dependencies packages grpcio.

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-i0uwqz32/grpcio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x6clk2ue-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-i0uwqz32/grpcio/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 360, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 725, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-i0uwqz32/grpcio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x6clk2ue-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-i0uwqz32/grpcio/
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command (for enabling PyProf)

```
pip3 install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--pyprof" --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```